# Advice optimizing kineticjs mobile game

Tags: html, kineticjs

I'm here to ask for help.

I'm trying to implement a simple Slots (casino) game for Android and iOS in html5.
My company asked me to look at frameworks that will speed up development.
So I've chosen KineticJS, because of good design and tutorials.

The project is mostly completed, but there is an issue:
it runs great on the iPad and iPhone5 but not so good in Android.
At the very least it must run on Android 2.3.

I used the kineticjs library to increase development speed and surely it helps, but the price for that is rather harsh.

I changed most of my Kinetic.Image objects to Kinetic.Shape, and it kinda helped performance a bit.
Also I stripped down some of the unused variables and now I'm using
this format:  (var i =0, ln = something.length; i < ln; i++) for loops.

I realize there is also a cache but I am kinda scared of losing control, since I am still developing it.

What else can I optimize to help solve this situation?
Maybe stripping down some of the highlights and animations in Android.

The worst situation so far is the loading of the client itself on Android.
It doesn't load on first load very well, sometimes it position objects incorrectly.

Well if you know any magic tricks to speed up Kineticjs game, then please let me know.

Sorry but I can't provide a demo right now, since I am still developing and it will affect testing.

Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem, making a kineticjs game and it runs slowly, or incorrectly on mobile devices. I hate to say it, but the problem is with the integrated mobile browsers. The devices have limited memory and even less in the browser. Only newer devices and newer browsers work faster. For example, my project works much better in Android, using Firefox Mobile. Faster than even Dolphin Browser or Chrome. In Windows Environment, the new Internet Explorer is very fast. Again, very device dependent, no matter how good your code.

Comment: Would it be possible for posting some code? It does depend a lot on device and browser, but still a simple game works fairly well in Android 2.3... so depends on what and how it is done

Comment: Actually I think found a way to optimize the code. Will try to experiment, hope it will run better.
I think I'm just using too many Objects. Some things in game doesn't need that many objects. Surely it creates load on processor and RAM.
My experience thought: if you want to show and play html5 game in Android use Chrome (even beta). :)
It's amazingly runs 3x times faster than inbuild browser.